# What is "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_name = VALUES(column_name)" in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, unique-key

I have a problem understanding the part '`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_name = VALUES (column_name)`' in my query.

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO user_mst(first_name,middle_name,last_name,corp_id,login_name,passwd,emp_num,designation,band_name,corp_mail_id,pers_mail_id,cont_phone,cont_mobile,passport_num,place_of_issue,passport_exp,user_status,user_class,hwc , gender,traveller_email_id,legal_entity) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,AES_ENCRYPT(?,?),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE traveller_email_id = VALUES(traveller_email_id)
```

I don't understand the part starting from '`On DUPLICATE KEY . . .`".

Please explain.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: @Bernhard, can you please make me understand the meaning of "VALUES(column_name)" ?

Comment: @Nico, I must say some of you are expert at marking a question  as 'duplicate'  hastily even when it's clearly not.

Comment: That's something you have to explain: which exact parts of your question are not covered by the documentation linked by Bernhard (which should cover the basic parts) and the linked question (which covers the basics of that query form in the question itself and more deep explanations in the answers)? If you don't think that the other questions help you, you should provide more context to your question